# Making elements overlap vis js timeline

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I am trying to overlap elements on top of each other. Like the example showing below: Point 5 and 6 inside item 4. Is there any option which I can pass to vis js timeline which will allow this to happen? Even if all elements overlap it is fine for me. I did try with styles/CSS but when moving timeline it messes up data representation.
Any pointer will be appreciated.[image: OverlapElements]

Comment: Did you try `stack: 'false'` option?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ajw5o8e2/1/ unable to get point 1 inside 2.

Comment: Sorry it is `stack: false` not `stack: 'false'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `stack: false` option to remove item stacking like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rexzing/wpxvL0tg/) example.